# Why are some videos appearing to make my screen extremely bright

Tags: macos, display, video, monterey

I'm browsing some videos, and I find that on some videos they appear to be extremely bright; even hurting my eyes a little. It doesn't happen with all videos, but a select few. They seem to bypass my macbook's current brightness level and sets it's own brightness to the max.

Why exactly are some of these videos blinding? is it a bug? and how do I prevent it prior to Apple fixing it?

It appears when I screenshot it, the image appears that only the video has been deep-fried or oversaturated, or just too bright. It's more noticeable on some videos than others when you compare the image to yourself directly looking at the screen with the video.

[Video in question...](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/oql4g6/touch_bar_has_short_slide_to_change_volume_or/)

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the video. You are explicitly altering the volume and the brightness on a static image (as far as I can tell). The reddit page is titled "Touch Bar has short slide for volume". Which model of MacBook Pro is it?

Comment: @benwiggy The things that happen in the video is not what this question is about. He's saying that when he views that particular video, he experiences a different brightness setting than expected.

Comment: Ah!! Good point. Hmm. The video does seem brighter on my 16" 2021 MBP than on my Mac Mini's monitor -- and it possibly doesn't respond to the Brightness controls as much -- but I wouldn't call it blinding.

Answer (score 0):

You could be experiencing this only for videos that are recorded as High Dynamic Range (HDR).

If that type of video is played back with the normal brightness setting, they would seem darker or more subdued in colors than intended. The only way to get proper (or at least as good as possible) playback of those videos is to increase the brightness to max for that video.

You see something similar on iPhones where the display is suddenly much brighter when playing back HDR10 content.

Comment: That's just awful. There has to be a way to turn that "feature" off. I run my MBP in a darkened room, and as a consequence I need reduced brightness. That videos can override my brightness setting is infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Right click desktop>display settings>scroll down and turn off "use HDR"

Comment: There's absolutely no "use HDR" setting on my Mac. I'm just stuck with videos that trigger automatic brightness overrides.